# MDCTextField in Objective C and Picker

Tags: objective-c, material-design, pickerview, material-components-ios

In my iOS apps written in Objective C, I have recently started using the Material Design components by Google. I have then transformed my UITextField into MDCTextField which look great.
When I have to select the value to enter into a list of possible values I have kept the "picker views" I had with my UITextField.

But I was wondering if another solution, more coherent with the design, was proposed with the Material Design library. I did not find any such facility in the documentation.

Thanks a lot for your help.
Dominique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the Material System does have a [Menu component](https://material.io/design/components/menus.html#), there is currently no iOS implementation for it. For now, we recommend using a native iOS UIPickerView.